# Android Studio. Animating a moving symbol/label

Tags: android, android-layout, android-animation

I am trying to create a simple program that prints a symbol at the 
**(x,y_const)** coordinate of the screen and then animates it moving
from coordinate **(x,y_const)** to **(x+somevalue,y_const)** and then back to **(x,y_const)**.

Aside from frame animation, what other ways of doing this exist?
I assume I could create a timer and refresh the position of a label?

Please help.
Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are plenty of tutorials on [Property Animation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/prop-animation.html).  You can also just use the [ViewPropertyAnimator](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewPropertyAnimator.html) on Views if you're targeting a high enough API level:

Ex:

```
View.animate().x(100).y(100).withEndAction(new Runnable(){
    public void run(){
        View.animate().x(0).y(0).start();
    }
}).start();
```